If services own their data, how do you deal with relations?
I've been studying different flavors of Service Oriented Architecture (SOA), Event-Driven Architecture (EDA), micro-services and related topics for the past few days.
I see it often recommended that each service should have their own database to minimize coupling which makes sense.
Let's consider Event-Carried State Transfer pattern where each service holds all the data it needs, some of it updated as reported by other services. The architecture tries to avoid cross-service API calls.
What's unclear to me is how should you handle relations in data. A common example around the topic is an e-commerce platform with services like "orders", "customers", "payments" and "inventory" where new orders trigger an event that "inventory" service uses to update the item quota. In any realistic system however, I'd expect relations between database entities like products, product categories, sellers, campaigns etc. And maybe, over time, both the "payments" service and "campaigns" service need to know which product belongs to which seller.
Now, this leads me to two thoughts:

It seems really sus having to maintain the relations of a relational database across multiple independent services. That would seem to make them implicitly coupled.
It seems unrealistic that those relations would not leak across services over time.

So my question is, would you duplicate not only some of the data but relations within into different services or is that a red flag and you should design your services such that there are no duplicated relations?

In your example are 'products', 'product categories', 'sellers', 'campaigns', and 'payments' assumed to be independent databases?

@JimmyJames not necessarily. They would be independent tables in a database, if I was building a monolith.

OK, but in the context of the question, are you assuming that is the way a SOA/microserivces architecture is supposed to be built?

No, not really. But my experience in building applications from scratch in general is that different relationships tend to accumulate. However I don't have experience in building SOA/microservices. So I was wondering if this is as common an issue as I imagine, or not an issue at all.

You have to decide where your data boundaries are.  It could be a single table, or a collection of tables.  Then your 'micro-services' adhere to those boundaries.   One thing to consider is the relationships of data. That's part of the design, how to chop up one system containing 100 tables into X systems with Y tables for each system.


So my question is, would you duplicate not only some of the data but relations within into different services or is that a red flag and you should design your services such that there are no duplicated relations?

Duplicating relations is not an immediate red flag, but as with all data you copy, you need to weigh the effort of keeping the copy up-to-date (plus the risk of missing an update) against the risk that the other service is unable to provide you the information you need when you need it (and the consequences of that).

I have already commented on @Steve's answer that I agree with him, unless you are "Amazon Scale" you probably need to think about whether MicroServices are really going to benefit your use case.
However lets assume for the sake of this answer, that you are "Amazon Scale".
In such a scenario it is likely that you will have duplicated data across systems, many systems may have concepts such as: Buyers, Sellers, Items, Orders and Payments. As such there are likely detailed design documents explaining the nuances of each of these entities and their fields/properties. Any change to these core objects, probably required co-ordination across multiple teams.
However at "Amazon Scale" there is probably significant functionality in each functional area, for example lets consider fulfillment (getting an item packed into a box and shipped to a customer). Amazon has many warehouses, it is likely that:

For popular items, multiple warehouses carry the same items.
Some customers could be serviced by different warehouses.
Which warehouse fulfills an order affects delivery routes / cost of delivery.
Different warehouses will be re-stocked on different schedules.
There is only a finite capacity of workers in the warehouse that can process a set number of orders in set time window.
Different orders have different priority based on shipping options selected.
...

The "coupling" and inter team communication of the high level concepts (Customers, Orders, etc) may be worth it to Amazon, to allow them to create a dedicated team that maintains the software that supports the fulfillment functionality.
However your mom and pop single location store that does an occasional web order doesn't have the same requirements, so can probably use a monolithic application maintained by a single team or dev - even though both companies are fundamentally solving the same problem.
TL;DR - You can not talk about a "Good Design" without talking about the size (and possibly layout) of the team that maintains it.

Yes, things that are problems at certain scales are simply not problems at other scales - and big doesn't mean more problems and small means less problems, instead both ends of the scale have different problems that simply don't exist for the other. Language differs too. Amazon is said to employ more developers (never mind their other workforce) than all the staples and paperclips currently inside boxes in my drawer - "micro" there means something completely different to most places.


In any realistic system however, I'd expect relations between database entities

You're not thinking with microservices. But let's explore your intuition here. Why do you expect a relationship?
Having a child refer to its parent? That's just a data field (depending on the type that is used for parent ID, commonly GUID or int).
Fetching child entities by a parent ID? That only needs an index on the parent ID column.
Cascaded deletes? Just like one table can trigger a delete in another table, so too can one microservice trigger a delete in another microservice.
You can also skip this, if you prefer services to just regularly run a check on all known parent IDs and delete any children whose parent no longer exists.
By and large, the only reason you need it to concretely exist is to ensure FK reference constraints. When you are creating a child, it tells you what parent it belongs to. But you're the child service, you have no idea whether that alleged parent exists or not.
I suspect you are currently relying on the database to protest if the alleged parent ID does not exist. But you can just as easily have the child service ask the parent service to confirm if parent 123 exists.

And maybe, over time, both the "payments" service and "campaigns" service need to know which product belongs to which seller.

Microservices do not mandate that every entity must be its own service. You draw reasonable boundaries as they apply to your use case.
If you have a high degree of correlation between vendors and their products, e.g. because you can hardly ever perform any operation on a product without knowing its vendor, then it sounds reasonable for them to be represented by a single service. High cohesion is a justification for them to live together.
There isn't a universally right/wrong answer to this. It's contextual. Weigh up the benefits of separating them, the benefits of keeping them together, and make the decision that best fits your use case.

Each service is a single source of truth. Other services may have stale copies of that truth but truth must come from a single source.
It's when you start to act like stale truth is truth that things go bad.
For example, if I have a receipt that says that 1 apple is $2 that only shows what I paid for the apple. It doesn't say you can buy an apple for $2.
This is a sneaky sort of bug because if you write code that assumes receipts have the current price your code will work fine, right up until someone changes the prices.

Imagine your receipt says that business-ID 123 is the company who sold the apple. Your receipt printer also has a mapping from business-ID to Company name. Then, there's also a separate service, a list of fruit suppliers that includes business-ID 123 and the name of the supplier. This is the kind of relationship of which I'm afraid of duplicating and accumulating.

@Antti_M why? Are you convinced that companies never change their names? (Whatever happened to Twitter?) Or are you convinced that stale truth is good enough in this case? Maybe you want to remove all interdependence. Fine. But now you're monolith service is the source of all truth.

Good questions. I'm concerned about a growing number of relations (products to sellers, but maybe a dozen others over time) that one would end up syncing across "independent" services. Hence my original question: is this something to avoid/worry about or not?

@Antti_M it's something to manage. Prefer a design that will react to a single service failure by degrading a single feature, not the entire system. A fundamental question hiding here is how big to let a service become. Best rule of thumb I've ever heard is no bigger than one person can manage.

Stale copies imply caching. Caching is indeed something you can consider as an optimization strategy. However, your price example is not an example of this. The current price of the product and the price you sold this product for during a specific order are conceptually two different things. One is not a stale version of the other. One may have originally been derived from the other but once created it started living its own life, not as a stale copy of the other.

@Flater Stale copies do not imply caching. Caching is deciding a stale copy is good enough. But a good caching strategy would not limit itself to receipts. After a certain amount of time it becomes silly to prefer the receipt price to updating the cache with a fresh copy from the single source of truth. The fact that they are conceptually different doesn't make the data useless. I means you need to remember what you're really looking at.

You need to put more thought into your data when you use these architectures.
So in your example

maybe, over time, both the "payments" service and "campaigns" service need to know which product belongs to which seller.

You have to define them in ways where they won't. You could do this with campaign for example having a list of included products.
Campaign
{
  id
  includedProductIds[]
}

All campaigns have included products, and when you want one which includes "all products from seller X" you just pull that list and set the campaign up with it. Rather than having the campaign call out for "get all products where seller = x"
You have to think about these things in a monolith as well, it's just that you don't face the immediate consequences of bad design.
Edit : based on Steve and Flatters comments

So what I'm arguing here, which perhaps I took for granted, is that there exist sensible divisions of data based on the domain and technical constraints and that microservices should be designed around those divisions.
So if you have a monolith database and need to implement

spec : a campaign which gives a discount to all products sold by seller X

You might implement it naïvely as :
Campaign
{
    sellerId
    IsProductDiscounted(productId)
    {
       sql  ="select * from product join seller, join campain where sellerId={sellerId} AND productID... and CampaignId..
       //run sql

    } 
}

It would work, but couples you to all that data and makes performance inconsistent across campaigns.
If you have microservice approach then you just cant write that implementation as you don't have the db access. It forces you to think hard about what a Campaign is in domain terms and how it can be defined so that multiple campaign types can be supported.
You define a Campaign in your domain as A group of products which have a discount applied and are able to implement this in a microservice as described above by just linking a set of product ids and having..
Campaign
{
    IsProductDiscounted(productId)
    {
        return productIds.Contains(productId);
    } 
}

Which is arguably a better solution, even if you have a monolith database.
So. I disagree that microservices should be split by team size. They should be split based on domain and for technical reasons such as performance, resilience, feature optionality etc etc
Furthermore, it's not just keeping the ids "in sync" in a different DB as DavidG suggests. We take a fundamentally different approach. The Campaign includes the products you selected when you set it up.
If you want it to match the spec as new products are added then there is a responsibility pushed out to update the campaign when this happens. Either to some other microservice, or a UI that prompts a user.
You allow orphaned ids and that desync in order to achieve loose coupling. That's what makes the service a microservice and not just a subsection of a monolith.

So having a bunch of separate lists of products for each seller and keeping those in sync is better than a single list?

thats not what im saying no

@DaveG: Ewan used a list of product IDs in their example, your comment seems to be responding to it being a list of products, which this isn't. The specific product data relating to those IDs can be pulled in live from the products service if and when it is needed. There is a potential for caching this if there's an optimization need, but that's not a design consideration. The key design focus here is on referring to external resources by their identifier and leaving the details to the resource's own service. The identifier is enough to access those details whenever you need them.

@Flater, aren't you just describing the relational model of data here, using different jargon? Different tables become "external resources", primary keys become "identifiers", etc.? There seems to be two schools of thought associated with microservices, those like yourself who seem to be trying to merge basic relational tenets with a certain kind of OO philosophy where every table or group of tables is hived off into its own "service" and an explicily designed frontage that you have to call through to access any data... (1/3)

...and those like myself who are arguing that microservices is basically a principle of how a developer workforce is organised (that teams should be small, and the functionality of a large development should be decomposed in a way that small teams have a useful amount of independence of action from one another) and how Conway's law then applies to the software design in consequence to how those staffing arrangements are made. (2/3)

The difference is that, in my argument, the number and shape of microservices corresponds to the organisational structure of the developers, and that shape is determined both by how much complexity each team can bite off and chew and by where reasonable partitions can be introduced in the larger system. Whereas in your argument, it's not clear why every database table doesn't just live in a separate service. (3/3)

@Steve (1) I'm not advocating for service-per-entity, see my answer for details (2) Subdivision for microservices is not solely done for the benefit of workforce organization. Scaling is another very good reason. There are cases to be made for there being more services than there are devs, let alone dev teams. (3) Whether or not all entities that refer to a external identifier alone, is open to nuance and interpretation. For example, you can keep vendors/products together (if you're so inclined), but still have a separate (e.g.) promotion service which is configured using product IDs.

@Flater, (1) I accept that's not your underlying view, and I'm addressing a composite and interpolated argument that I'm attributing to you and others, but there's no obvious logic in the argument why recursively splitting things up until you reach the table level is inappropriate, if splitting things up is presented as a beneficial thing. Your own answer more or less suggests maximum splitting to start, then combining certain related things only if necessary. (1/3)

(2) Scaling of the workforce is the main reason I'm arguing is characteristic of microservices - since the definition of what is "micro" is by reference to the size of the development team who oversee that microservice (a few heads max). I accept there could be other reasons for splitting services, but not every service is driven by microservice design logic. If one person is looking after 3 services entirely, then I might venture to say that is one microservice - because the microservice is the independent work/facility of that person/team, not the floorplan of the hardware. (2/3)

(3) I'm not naysaying that approach to using identifiers, I'm just saying it reflects basic normalisation principles of the relational model. The relational model doesn't preclude cross-context foreign keys, but ordinary database design work does proceed from the assumption that you don't split things across contexts unless you have to for specific reasons, because you erode or lose the simplicity and functionality that arises from keeping all data stored under the scope of a single engine (the scope of the single engine typically being the definition of a single "context"). (3/3)

@Steve (1) "If you can split things then that must invariably mean you should never stop splitting things further" is an asinine interpretation (of any guideline, for that matter) and it is not a good faith argumentation. (2) You're repeating yourself, ignoring my point entirely. Deflecting it as "that part is not microservice design then" is not a good faith argument either. (3) If you think microservices should be designed based on a relational model averse to any splitting, then you've not understood the most basic cornerstone of microservices. (4) Verbosity does not make you right.

@Flater, well (3) is the question at stake, isn't it.

@Steve ive updated to better explain

@Flater yes, what you said.

@DaveG I have addressed your point

@Ewan, although you're unequivocal that it isn't about the organisation of developers for you, I still can't discern what it actually is then. It no clearer to say (paraphrasing) "we organise things into parts for various technical reasons", because that's what every developer already does anyway, whether they are seeking to apply a "microservice" architecture or not. I can't discern what the distinguishing features or rationales are. Your example just appears to suggest different styles of coding the database calls from the client application.

@Steve do you not agree that avoiding the coupling of campaign and seller is a better design choice regardless of whether you implement as a MS?

If you don't agree that some seperation in your design is better than none, then yeah i'm not sure how you get away from 1 massive db == best. And if you don't agree that some coupling of models is better than none, then i dont see how you get away from one db+stack per class == best

The idea that you just dole out code based on team size obvs doesn't work if you don't take dependencies into account. So you must be decoupling somewhere, surely you put some thought into the design of your products when you make those splits? it not just "we got to 100 classes, split there and the next 100 goto team 2"?

All im saying is that MS forces you to put more thought into that design split, because you cant just fall back on "well i technically can access everything".

@Ewan, well I'm suggesting you'd stick with one DB engine to begin with, and then start dividing things up when specific good reasons are found. For example, it's always been very common to hive off reporting workloads to secondary equipment, or to have different computer systems per company site. But talking about the product list being separate from the customer list is already at the preposterous and risible end of the scale - the average ERP system where you have considerable varieties of master data, is that they run on a single database engine. (1/2)

On doling out code according to team size, obviously I'm not suggesting the doling out isn't complicated, or that technical constraints wouldn't make some ways of doling out responsibility inadvisable. But when it comes to scaling the workforce to cope with a large development, one common (maybe naive) approach is simply to keep adding workers to the general pool, who will be asked to work on whatever part currently needs to be tackled. My understanding of microservices is to cousel against this, saying the system should be decomposed into small teams looking after semi-autonomous parts. (2/2)

@Steve Your concrete proposals strongly indicate you're either not across or actively combating microservice principles. Recommending using a single database as a baseline flies in the face of the independent lifecycle that microservices represent. Your whole ERP bit is unfounded, at best anecdotal about one way of doing it. Microservices also do not advise how you should or shouldn't be staffing your teams. I don't know where you're getting all this from. But one thing is clear, your suggestions are not in line with a microservice mindset, both in spirit and in practical application.

@Flater, consider Fowler, reading at least the next few paragraphs starting from the heading "Organized around Business Capabilities": https://martinfowler.com/articles/microservices.html. This wasn't the source of my information - I'm not sure what my sources were tbh, because I've mostly been writing off the cuff today - but as you can see other thinkers clearly seem to think workforce organisation is a fundamental aspect to it. You're not talking to me as if you merely disagree with this line of thinking - you're talking to me like you've never even heard this alien idea before. (1/3)

On ERPs and the like, I've been familiar with the internals of a few major ones as well as a couple of bespoke ones, and I assure you they have all run on a single transactional database engine. Obviously I can't claim to cover what every in-house developer has made bespoke. But serious technologies that run the world's commerce (as might use things like "product" and "customer" lists)? They work from a core of a single database engine with a large mixture of business data inside. (2/3)

However I'm not trying to say every business works from one computer and one united data store - that is realistic perhaps only in a small business (and maybe not even then). What I am saying is that a single application is typically designed with a single integrated data store if possible, and the design regresses conservatively from that starting point for various substantial reasons. I don't see microservices as challenging this basic wisdom, according to the way I've interpreted it, which is that large developments should consist of small teams looking after semi-autonomous areas. (3/3)

@Steve "I'm suggesting you'd stick with one DB engine to begin with, and then start dividing things up when specific good reasons are found" You might find that hard when all your components are deep linked to each others tables. I have to agree with flater, I think you have got the wrong end of the stick with micoservices. The idea is to split first to keep products separate, not split later to keep teams small.

@Ewan, those deep and complicated linkages are usually essential when talking about basic corporate data, and are what makes the data rich in usefulness. It's often not possible to really separate them - other than in the degenerate sense that they may be stored separate at rest, but every activity first involves bringing them back together into one context, and the separateness of storage simply becomes a cause of additional complexity but solves nothing. I really do struggle to make sense of what I'm hearing. (1/2)

If things do become sufficiently complex, then you don't cut through the middle of linkages between basic data, you organise core and auxiliary functions. Like you might have products, customers, and price books in the core, which allow basic business transactions to be recorded, but you have a complicated price-setting analysis function, and this periodically feeds updates back to the core - and in theory, neither needs the other fully online, so they can be developed by their teams with reasonable autonomy. Anyway I don't want to force more discussions if it may not be desired. (2/2)

No I think this is a misunderstanding of MicroService Architecture. The idea is exactly to cut those linkages and have separate components which can be arranged/orchestrated as needed. You can argue that this is obvious and doesn't require microservices, but clearly OPs question shows that it isn't.

@Steve: There's no point arguing this. Your approach is a valid one, but it is not a microservice-oriented one. Therefore, in context of a microservice guideline, your guide to monolithic design is off-topic. Your belief that this data can't be separated (or not without a net negative impact) is simply not a universal truth in the way you're pretending that it is. Either you don't understand microservices, or you are consciously turning this into a monolith vs microservices right or wrong debate. That's just not what this question nor this answer is about.

@Steve And before you start with your multi-comment response that repeats your same points: I'm well aware of all the points you've made, including your mentions of multiple services (not just a monolith). But suggesting that separate services are backed by a single DB engine is not a correct application of microservice architecture; this is what's colloquially known as a distributed monolith and it really just is another monolith in sheep's clothing.

@Flater, you keep saying you're getting me, but you're not. I never said multiple services must be backed by one DB engine.

@Ewan, you appear to talk as if the "linkages" themselves are somehow discretionary or of only subsidiary importance in the design. My experience of a product list, for example, is that on its own it's a very simple and fairly useless thing, and that all the design complexity arises from how it is linked together with other kinds of data. That complexity is present when the data is co-located under the same DB engine, and the DB engine is a complicated technology in its own right that provides a lot of facilities that ease many design complexities. (1/3)

I understand that way of doing things, and I've seen many very complex application designs under those terms. The design process is about putting everything together "as needed". Now, you say that putting each table of data, or couple of related tables, in their own "service" will make things easier. I can immediately see which things must become somewhat harder and how. What I don't see, is which things become easier, or how. (2/3)

You and Flater are both saying that I'm somehow fundamentally opposing the microservices principles, but I seem to have a completely different interpretation of what microservices are - supported as I now have with links to Martin Fowler - which I am not then opposing. The issue is still about what you are saying microservices even are - it maybe equates to saying "every database engine should look after 1 or 2 tables", when most engines (at least client-server ones) are in fact technologies designed to cope with thousands of tables of data with myriad users in each running instance. (3/3)

@Steve "What I don't see, is which things become easier, or how." In light of this, how do you think this impacts your ability to judge the benefits of, and therefore main purpose of, a microservice architecture? Your persistent focus on database tables as a metric for complexity and capability is missing the point. There is no evolution to any of your responses, you just come up with different ways to phrase the same skewed perspective and then ponder what possible benefits there could possibly exist outside of your understanding, ignoring how often they have already been explained to you.

@Flater, we're not even working from a common understanding about what microservices are, and you're regularly expressing annoyance. I have my own interpretation about "development team autonomy", and you have another interpretation which is more like "extensively distributed storage". Nobody seems to have taken issue with the internal logic of my interpretation, merely that what I'm talking about "isn't microservices" (but presumably something else, which would make it irrelevant in this context). (1/2)

There's apparently some overlap between the two in the sense that I accept team autonomy involves some distribution of storage, and you presumably see one of the benefits of distributed storage as autonomy of developers. Well, I'm not fighting for the crown of which gets called microservices, so, whatever, each person might be emphasising a different appendage of the same animal here. But then I try to solicit how extensively distributed things should be, what guidelines there should be. (2/3)

And the impression I'm getting back is of something really extreme, verging on "total non-co-location", almost as if distribution of data is seen as more desirable than co-location. At the very least, if you want to rock up and actually advocate such a radical approach (which is inconsistent with any working computer application I've ever seen the insides of, and where distribution of data is always a cause of additional complexity, even if some distribution is often considered architecturally necessary), you might come prepared to explain yourselves a little better to everyone. (3/3)

@Steve yeah im not sure which bit of my answer you disagree with. I give the example of the loosely coupled Campaign vs a tightly coupled version. MS forces you to choose the loosely coupled version. The benefit is (amongst a list of things) you chose the loosely coupled version. Its this loose coupling, to the extent of completely separating the apps and using out of process communication, which is the raison d'etra of MS.

Now if you want a hard rule on when you can loosely couple and when you cant, obvs that's based on the details of the domain logic and tech limitation. Not team size or code complexity or anything else.

@Steve: I can only keep pointing out that your storage-first considerations just don't align with microservice architecture considerations. It doesn't start from a baseline approach of designing your service so as to optimize the underlying persistence storage device. The focal point of microservices is, as the name suggests, on the service, not the persistence store. Any and all metrics start favor persistence concerns over service concerns fail the microservice approach at the first pass. If you keep focusing on persistence benefits alone, you remain blind to everything else.

@Ewan, you did give that example previously, and tbh it raised more questions for me than I thought I could sensibly seek answers to in the comments. The issue it seems is this: you equate the distribution of storage with less coupling of the data.
I can't agree with this claim. I think it's possible to scatter data around in storage that nevertheless is (and remains) coupled - and which is coupled not because of a design flaw, but because it is intrinsically rich with interconnections. I don't want to post another unwanted 4-comment marathon elaborating on that, but that's what it's about.

@Steve At some point, you're going to have to start thinking about more than just how rich your persistence store could be. By having your persistence store richly connected, it creates dependencies which in turn inhibit any independent lifecycle of your alleged microservices (i.e. separate services backed by a shared persistence store), which cuts into one of the major (if not the) cornerstones of a microservice architecture. But you seem to stubbornly keep talking only about persistence, no matter how often it gets pointed out; so you'll just have to keep not understanding it I guess.

@Steve And again, this isn't about right or wrong, it's about judging something by a completely irrelevant metric (to it). You clearly care a lot about your optimized persistence store and how all your underlying data is cohesively linked together. That's perfectly fine. But if you judge the value of an architecture by that metric alone (or as the primary consideration), then you're never going to agree with microservices. That's not an objective review of microservice architecture in and of itself; it's just that your main interests don't align with that of a microservice architecture.

@Flater, to me, the only thing the computer does is store or process data. My relationship to it, is to design and supervise how it does those things. You beseech me to "focus on the service" and not the storage, but what is the "service" but the storage and processing of data (both the details of which I design, so that when other users press some button, it does some complicated routine thing that I specified it should do when that button is pressed)? I can't make sense of how you're telling me to think differently about it. (1/2)

I only care about the storage to the extent that it's something I have to design, and I have to design correct algorithms that manipulate data in storage. The structure of storage concerns how data is placed at rest, and algorithms specify the mechanical activities of the computer with that data - the computer is a machine with storage and moving parts. The two are always fitted to one another. The art is all about managing the complexity of this task. I say with a wry smile, do you not design these things like me? Are your concerns otherwise than storage and algorithms? (2/2)

@Steve do you not see the difference between linking to a productid and linking to products with seller id = x?

@Ewan, no I didn't really follow that point. I struggled even to guess who the "seller" was in context - are we talking about the suppliers of your business, or are we talking about you running a middle-man platform where both sellers and buyers are a form of public user of your application? Why does one code example have an SQL snippet and the other none? Are the variables which are mentioned but not declared implicitly class-level fields? Why does a seller variable feature explicitly in one of the code examples but disappear from the other? I couldn't see what was being shown by it all.

@Steve hmm ok, useful feedback, I prefer to make quite terse answers aimed at the OPs immediate problem rather than long discussions on theory. In the context of the question, I assume the ecommerce platform is allowing users to both buy and sell products, like amazon, so a seller is the entity which is "selling" the product through the intermediary of the software platform.

One example has SQL because it demonstrates the kind of deep link that the OP is asking how to cope with in a MS architecture. ie "If I make a Campaign MS, how do i handed that it need access to data that is unrelated to the campaign" This example shows how you might approach the problem if you didnt have to split the data and acts as a baseline to demonstrate the issue at hand#

The second example, shows that by rethinking the definition of a campaign, so that it can represent the concept rather than the immediate requirement, which as you point out you should be doing regardless, You can Have a microservice for campaign without any external data. Thus solving the issue at hand

Yes, I exclude the full list of vars as I think its implicit and want short examples. The sellerId features in one example, and not the other because the second example is showing how you can achieve the same effect without the sellerId

So really my answer is unrelated to your discussion with flater about your idea that MS are just a way to split work between teams. I don't think that is a theory that is commonly held at all, I think you are misinterpreting the links you posted to support it. But I can see if that is your view on what MSs are, then you would be confused by my answer, which kind of takes it as read that MSs are about splitting by feature/concept/domain, which I think is implicit in the OPs question and the generally accepted defintion.

@Ewan, I think the OP is seeking to examine theory, not looking for conclusory solutions to an immediate problem. I'm still not myself following your explanation of the scenario - I can see what is changed, but not how the original case was a "problem" in a meaningful way or the change a "solution" - but as before I'm reluctant to press because I suspect it would unleash a discussion of enormous scale to deal with the true complexity of the topic. (1/3)

As for my interpretation, I'm not saying you don't split teams according to "feature/concept/domain", and because I'm saying each microservice corresponds to the team which make it, then in my interpretation too, microservices still split according to feature/concept/domain. The difference is the implied granularity here. You're splitting to the point where one guy - who apparently might be the only developer in the building - may be looking after dozens of microservices by himself. I'm saying that's absurd. (2/3)

You can see Fowler considers the case of six guys per service, and six guys per six services, but not one guy looking after six services, because that is inconsistent with his understanding of microservices being organised around business functions, not that every single piece of different data is given a microservice of its own. It's implicit that business functions themselves are organised around the management of staff. It's this scale/granularity issue, which is the problem for me - you seem to think the word "micro" gives licence to split everything to a subatomic level. (3/3)

@Steve the original case is a problem because its breaking the rule of microservices having their own DB and/or owning their data. I'm surprise you didn't understand this point as surely its the crux of your argument against distributed data? The discussion has run on so long I wouldn't worry about the scale of it now. Also, we do seem to be simply reiterating the same point here.

If you agree that MS are split by domain, then stop bringing up team size. Its irrelevant. If you are using MS architecture the number of MS doesn't change whether you have 100 devs or just 1.

@Ewan, but there's no real information about the storage arrangements. It goes from ostensibly preparing an SQL call to ostensibly looking up an in-memory list. There's no evidence of whether SQL has been purged from the application, or whether the calls have just been moved to some other implicit place in the code. You're writing in C#/Java with no file access shown, so you're apparently on the client side or in a middle layer. It's impossible to infer the overall floorplan of the storage - to say whether "campaigns" are under the same storage engine as "products" or whatever else, or not.

I don't see the 6 guys thing in your link, But sure team size is something people consider when organising teams. It's something to avoid when designing software though, so you don't fall into a conways law trap. Its trivial to see that in a small company you can have more features and therefor MS than developers. Some of those features are complete and sit for years without needing any dev work, some might be super complex and require a large team. It has no impact on the number of Micoservices

@Steve you are a bit fixated on the storage, it doesn't really matter if sql has been purged from example 2 or not. As a Microservice it cant access seller data

@Ewan, I'm agreeing that MS are split by "domain" because it is a logical implication of two aspects of my interpretation. One, that development teams themselves should be split according to what can be reasonably deemed conceptual "domains", once the staff becomes large enough that a few of them cannot just cover everything, and two, that the MS should reflect the organisation of the teams which do the development in the first place. So while I'm not denying that MS will end up being split according to domain, the controlling factor is still how the development teams are split.

@Ewan, search for the word "dozen" - used repeatedly in the term "half-a-dozen". Conway's Law isn't a "trap" - it just says that computer systems get arranged in the image of how their designers and supervisors arrange themselves. In a small company with only one developer, the entire "domain" is what that sole developer looks after. There is therefore no splitting.

@Ewan, it's like I said to Flater, I don't know what you even mean by "fixated on storage". Structured storage + algorithms = computer programs. It's bread and butter stuff to be concerned with where you're putting data, or getting it from. Perhaps the issue here is not my fixation but a true blind spot on your part?

@Steve ahh yeah i see, yeah "pizza team" is a common term, but this is just an aside about teams. I can see we could have a discussion about conways law as well. The idea is that if your software design matches your org structure, it isn't a good design as the two should be unrelated.

re storage, yes, obviously in an actual implementation you would have to chose some sort of storage for example 2. But for the purposes of the question the only relevant factor is that seller data can't be directly accessed by the campaign microservice. Let sayu i update the examples to show an sql database for example 2 with campaign and campaign_productId tables. and example 1 has a full db with product->seller relationships. Does that make it clearer for you?

is it just that you dont agree that microservices shouldnt share databases?

Just from you comments it does seem like you have a fundamental misunderstanding of microservices. Are you implementing them as a distributed monolith as flater says, with multiple services but a single DB?

@Ewan, oh come on, Fowler certainly isn't the final law on the matter, but it's quite clear what his position is: "The microservice approach to division is different, splitting up into services organized around business capability.". You can say your teams shouldn't be organised like the software, but then you're against Conway (who says not that it is a design principle, but that the correspondence will emerge naturally from the nature of development activity).and you're against Fowler. I only feel the need to quote them to show myself that I'm not the one going mad!

I'm not "against" conway, software does tend to resemble company structure, but he's saying that's a bad thing! not that you should aim for it!

When MF talks about "business capability" he doesnt mean, "the ability of developers to support software" he means "things the business can do" ie features. "The microservice approach to division is different, splitting up into services organized around business capability. Such services take a broad-stack implementation of software for that business area, including user-interface, persistant storage, and any external collaborations"

"... each product is split out into a number of individual services communicating via a message bus"

@Ewan, I've said it more than once now: I haven't made the claim you're attributing to me! I haven't said "microservices should share databases". I'm also not taking a hard-line contrary position and saying they mustn't share (even for special reasons), but I accept the principle is that the data of a service should be stored independently of any other service, and access to or change of that data should be via calls to the service.

" I accept the principle is that the data of a service should be stored independently of any other service" Then why do you question the lack of detail on the storage implementation in my examples?

@Ewan, no, Fowler invokes Conway's Law to explain that, if you arrange the teams in the way Fowler says is wrong (and which is not consistent with microservices), then the arrangement of software artefacts will follow this wrongheaded arrangement of staff due to Conway's Law. Fowler is not saying you should therefore defy Conway's Law. He's saying you should organise the staff differently so that, when Conway's Law operates, the arrangement of the software artefacts will then resemble a correct arrangement of the development staff.

If i remember correctly in conways paper its actually design teams the software design mimics, so there is no argument that matching the support structure is good design. Its just two designs both saying they are the best, but both match the setup of the teams that designed them, ergo the design isn't based on a conceptual "best"

MF does mention Conway's law but its a bit of an aside. If you know about conways law but choose to org the teams in a particular way anyway then conways law isnt operating.

you could equally well have cross functional teams working on a monolith

"Then why do you question the lack of detail on the storage implementation in my examples?" - because the issue, it seems, is how fine-grained you are proposing splitting up the storage of data, far beyond anything I consider sane. In my interpretation of microservices, there is a natural limitation of this storage-splitting based on how split up the development staff can possibly be. You can't split up an individual developer, so the minimum size of a microservice is what a competent full-time developer can reasonably cope with on his own. (1/2)

Because you deny this limitation, and you deny that MS has got anything to do with the organisation or capacity of the development staff at all, then it's unclear why you can't just keep recursively splitting things up until everything is as split as having each database table (a table being a simple, structurally-regular, widely-known concept that I'm using as an informal measure for the complexity and variety of data being handled) in a completely independent context and under a different storage engine. (2/2)

You could "equally well have cross-functional teams working on a monolith". But then that isn't "microservices" according to any of us, is it?

"the minimum size of a microservice is what a competent full-time developer can reasonably cope with on his own." This is simple to disprove. Consider a consulting or outsourced company where developers work on projects for many customers. Are you going to bundle all their applications into one? Obviously not. Consider a Car deisgn company that has a small app unrelated to its main business. Maybe it emails a newsletter. Are you going to bundle that in with the car design app just because its too small to take up 100% of a developers time?

consider a microservice thats been completed and doesn't need further work, are you going to bundle it into a larger project because it only takes up 1% of the original developers time and they have moved onto something else?

You split by feature, or to use MFs language "business capability" even if you just have one developer, you have the same number of microservices

"it's unclear why you can't just keep recursively splitting things up until everything is as split as having each database table" Because you split by feature, so you don't split by sub feature. The split is defined by the domain, no-one is suggesting you split more than the domain requires

@Ewan, you're just disguising the same essential point with the extra trappings of consultancy or outsourcing now. Your point is still this: what if a single developer looks after a dozen supposed microservices? My answer is the same: that's against the principles of microservices in the first place, as I understand them. It's not intrinsic to outsourcing or consulting that one developer must end up looking after many microservices - a consultant can advise an in-house team then move on, or outsourcers can allocate specific individuals indefinitely to specific customers. (1/2)

Fowler says something related under heading "Products not Projects". In terms of looking after two unrelated small apps - that is, which do not interact with each other at all, and are very undemanding to look after - then perhaps one person could end up looking after more than one of these. But in what sense are these then a set of interacting "microservices"? Surely they're just small, fully-integrated, fully-independent monoliths? (2/2)

@Ewan, if you have only one developer, then you wouldn't be using microservices, because there's no development workforce that needs to be organised into business functions. I know this must be starting to sound like "turtles all the way down", but (unless I become confused myself...) I'm going to return to the same touchstone every time, which is about the organisation of a development workforce, and that a microservice is a facility overseen by a single development team (of one or more individuals) within a context where the scale of development admits more than just one such facility.

@Ewan, as an aside and not addressing any specific point above, you may want to read what Fowler has to say about Conway's Law: https://martinfowler.com/bliki/ConwaysLaw.html. it's a much more recent article from him than the original one on microservices, and in it he mentions microservices and the "inverse Conway maneouver".

@Steve we all understand that you think MS are purely about organising a workforce. This is incorrect. We can see from your comments where you went wrong interpreting MFs article, confusing "business capability" with "the capability of the business". I've given you 3 or 4 examples of obvious cases showing it doesn't work and clearly explained the correct interpretation MS => product/feature. Which frankly MF belabours in his articles. You just keep stating the same thing "MS == teams!".


It's irrelevant to the question at hand, which is "assuming i've split this thing into 2 microservices, how do i handle links between the data?"
You don't object to more than one MS per team.
You accept MS should be split according to the domain


It seems the only problem you have is that MS shouldn't be too small. But no-one is suggesting this "1 MS per table" straw man idea you think we are on a slippery slope to and if you accept the domain logic split, it's not clear why you think this will lead to tiny MSs.


tbh I am kinda stumped by this "1 competent dev" sizing, I didn't really expect to change your mind, but the more you think about it the less sense it makes. What if you have a team of 2 devs with two MSs. can they make a third as long at the MS itself is not smaller than the 1 full time dev limit? What if its a team of 1 dev with 1 MS, why can't he make a second MS? What if one dev leaves the 2 MS 2 dev team? What bad thing happens?

What if I have a high performing x1000 dev, should they write massive Microservices? or scale them back to some global average?

Do I have to employee teams of devs just to sit next to their MSs doing nothing when there is no work required on them? Or can i let them work on other things?

@Ewan, I haven't yet identified any error on my part in interpreting Fowler. I keep starting from "MS=teams" because you keep putting what you believe is some decisive contradiction to me, and I merely explain that it clearly isn't a contradiction when you start from my interpretation of MSes. It's only a contradiction when you start from your interpretation - which I already reject. I believe the perceived MS/teams connection is patently clear in Fowler's articles that I've linked, and the underlying logic of that connection is associated with Conway's Law. (1/4)

So the MS/teams connection is not just baldly asserted, it's well-substantiated. On your items, I'm skipping (1). On (2), indeed I don't "object to more than one MS per team", but not because I think is a characteristic arrangement of microservices, but because I accept there are bound to be situations where there is an overall system of microservices undoubtedly present (according to my team-based interpretation), yet someone ends up lumped with a series of muddled or small residual concerns which get manifested as separate microservices. (2/4)

The reason they do not all get merged into one combined microservice that this one person looks after, is because they are seen to be unrelated to each other (i.e. they don't interact with one another), but they are each nevertheless interacting with the larger body of microservices present. And the one guy, because he can fart and chew gum at the same time, and because each developer is probably paid for a full-time effort, and because each of these small residual microservices is trivial yet isn't apt to be combined, he ends up looking after more than one. (3/4)

That's the grounds on which I accept the possibility. On (3), yes, the problem I have is that MSes shouldn't be "too small", and I'm unable to get any guidance from you about what you think is too small. I'm clear about my guidance - one MS per development team. So there's a natural limit indicated that you won't have more separate MSes than separate teams in your firm. The indications I've had about where you draw the line on "too small", come across to me as utter madness insofar as I can discern any indication at all. (4/4)

"What if I have a high performing x1000 dev, should they write massive Microservices?" - well, usually what you'd do is allocate them to the more complicated work in the team, to the teams which handle the more complicated work, or to teams which have fewer members. So there's three ways of soaking up the extra productivity of an individual, without the absurdity of a "massive microservice" (of presumably disjoint concerns). Instead, it results in this individual doing a greater proportion of a single team's work - perhaps handling alone what would take any other team 5 people.

I have clearly stated the split multiple times, as dose MF in the articles you quote and point 3 in the comment you are replying to. a quick search on google gives the top answer : "The most common strategy for designing microservices is decomposition by subdomain - you apply domain-driven design to identify the different domains of your system, and turn them into microservices provided they have sufficient automony"

"one MS per development team" wow thats a big change from your 6 in a team of 6 from earlier. I wonder how you ever make your second microservice. Again you are ignoring all my points and questions and just restating your mistaken and irrelevant belief.

its a bit disappointing that your "discussion of enormous scale" turns out to be just to be a loop back to that same comment

@Ewan, there is no intrinsic scale indicated when talking of a conceptual "domain". We seem well apart on what we think the appropriate scale is. I didn't personally say "six in a team of six" - I was directly quoting Fowler, who indicated a range of between "a team of six looking after one MS" to "a team of six looking after six MSes". In other words, a people-to-MS ratio of 6:1 to 1:1. We keep looping because so far you're not defeating my interpretation of MS as being the one commonly understood, nor showing that my interpretation has an internal contradiction or absurdity.

@Steve "there is no intrinsic scale indicated when talking of a conceptual "domain"." correct! I think i said this 20 comments up. that means you can have tiny MSs when the domain requires it, or huge ones! its not related to team size in any way

I mean i have pointed out several absurdities, but really if you accept, as you have in more than one comment now, that the domain has something to do with the split, and that, as i keep pointing out, no-one is suggesting nano services. What is the practical difference? companies have dev teams, dev teams support apps, some apps are MSs. It's you who are saying that there is some conceptual problem with a MS being smaller than some vague measure of dev effort and not backing it up.

@Ewan, you may have said that 20 comments up, and then when I say "well does that mean every microservice has just one or two tables of data?" - chosen to represent an absurdly small scale in my view, clearly far less than the granularity I suggest is reasonable - you then say I'm "straw-manning" you. You can't have it both ways. I'm not forcing you to take a single universal position on the point - you could say "well perhaps a MS could have only one or two tables in strange or exceptional cases, but typically there would be at least say 20 or maybe 50 tables in a microservice". (1/2)

You could say that, if it were your view. If you simply won't be drawn at all on this issue of scale, then I'm happy to drop the matter, since it seems everything that could be said, has already been said, and we've both extensively explained to one another how we are working from very different ideas of what microservices are even about fundamentally, and we can't even agree whose side Martin Fowler is on!  (2/2)

If the domain size is one or two tables, then yes the microservice is one or two tables. There's no such thing as "too small to be a microservice" I'm not sure how you have managed to interpret my comments differently? I'm still no wiser on why you think small MSs are bad or who you think is saying all MSs should be small?

because you split by domain, the MS is the size of the domain it represents. What about this idea is causing you to worry? @Steve

@Ewan, so why does describing the typical size of a microservice, in your experience, seem to be the hardest word here? You can tell me all day that a MS size may vary with the size or complexity of the domain. The question is, what are the typical sizes of the domains associated with your microservices (or what do you think would be the typical size)? I've already staked my claim in the ground of one-MS-per-person, with all that implies. You say it's not about people but domains, so how big are your domains typically, and how many microservices would one person typically be in charge of?

gona say it again, there is not typical size. I've got tiny stateless nano services that are just aws functions and massive, all of accounts microservices.

people arent "in charge" of micro services, They run without error for years. cross functional teams are assigned feature work and bugs as they come up

@Ewan, I strongly suspect you mean "cross-functional teams" in the sense of "cross-domain teams" - teams who look after multiple domains, each one associated with a microservice. That is quite clearly in opposition to how Fowler is characterising the relationship between on the one hand development teams, and on the other hand microservices as artefacts those teams make. For him, "cross-functional" means something more like "full-stack" - across the technical functions that sometimes characterise how developers get organised. (1/2)

Anyway can we agree there is obviously two theories here? Like "agile", I can only conclude that microservices seems to be a buzzword that encompasses a very wide variety of practices and opinions, many of them utterly opposed to one another, or which involve highly ambiguous claims that are very difficult to interpret or apply to practice - and our own differences of opinion exemplify this. (2/2)

@Steve the problem is not that you have a different theory, the problem is you aren't saying how your theory applies in the case and what the pros/cons of following one theory over the other are. You cant just keep saying "Small MS go against my theory! raaah!"

@Ewan, well that's a very pithy reduction of my argument! In terms of the size of MSes, in the theory I prefer, a service that is looked after by one team, and perhaps as little as one individual, is by definition a small service - a microservice. There is nothing specifically in that theory to preclude even smaller services, there is just no cause for smaller services within the framework of that theory, because once you've split down to the individual developer then no further division of know-how or intellectual labour between developers is possible. (1/3)

I think amongst the main public proponents of microservices, they are employees of major technology corporations, and their main argument was targeted against overly large software developments maintained by overly large teams. They are primarily talking to fellow managers of staff who work in similar-sized firms where there are enough developers that overly large teams are both a real possibility, and a common tendency. I don't think they are primarily concerned with the solo developer or the small in-house function. (2/3) l

I think your preferred theory is addressing different concerns. I think it's more about how the individual developer manages complexity, or time-shares their attention across the system. And I think this is a sufficiently different concern that it would be argued about separately. Managing different tasks that one person will execute at different times, is not just a smaller scale version of designing jobs that different people will execute concurrently. There's no pro/con comparison because I don't think either theory would apply to the domain of the other. (3/3)

@Steve you have outlined your theory (again) but not provided any info about what it predicts about my answer that prompted you to bring it up.

@Ewan, you put a couple of things to me in your last comment. You said I hadn't explained how my theory applied "in this case". I think I have explained (through my own answer and all these other comments) how it applies, so if you don't agree then I'd need something more to go on about what an explanation does or doesn't look like. You also said I hadn't shown "pros/cons". I've answered that above by arguing that I believe the two theories are at cross-purposes and therefore wouldn't be properly contrasted like that. I've also tried to add detail that I thought could be helpful.

@Steve, sorry I don't see where you address my answer, please spell it out. as to pros and cons, forget about my explanation of why your theory is wrong and just say how your theory applies to my answer

@Ewan, at this stage I've completely lost the thread of what we're talking about. Shall we draw the veil over it?

@Steve you could just quickly read back through the comments?

@Ewan, sorry I don't mean that I've lost access to the comments, I mean reading those comments no longer leads me to a place where I feel like I understand what you're talking about in your latest comments, or how to meet the questions you are now putting. And I'm thinking we've reached a level of complexity which is not apt to be continued. If you have any remaining questions for me, it needs to be a clearer than "What did you mean by it all? Re-read what you've said above.". I personally think we need to go from the top again on this, but that would mean a new Q&A.

@Steve hmm, well its sad to see it all came to nothing when pressed. My take away is that you are still not understanding the concept of splitting by domain. You fail to answer the OPs question of how to deal with a domain split ir show how your idea of splitting by workforce helps

@Ewan, personally I found it all very useful. I'm not trying to avoid further discussion on the topic, I just think we've reached that point as arguments sometimes do when you need to start again at the top, and with a more generous number of words for reorientation than these comments really allow. I'm convinced at this stage that we're discussing two different animals each claiming the same name of "microservices" and with some complicated overlap of ideas.

@Steve if you don't like the term microservices, lets just say "apps"

@Ewan, it's not an argument about terminology. I'm just saying the fact that these two different architectural principles go by the same name, has contributed initially to confusion amongst ourselves and no doubt contributes to popular confusion.

I think one is called cross functional teams and the other is called microservices. But you still haven't explained the relevance of either

The idea of the microservice is to have independently deployable services. This means that if one microservice is responsible for Product:

you should be entitled to change the Product without having to change the other microservices, even in case of relationships.
conversely, others should be entitled to change as well without impacting the Product.

The consequence is that relationships are either represented on both sides or on one side (depending on navigability requirements), knowing only the bare minimum of the object at the other side.
This potential (minimalistic) duplication is the cost for the flexibility, scalability and maintenability of the microservice architecture.
But microservices do not necessarily mean that every aggregate deserves its own microservice. Two aggregates that are very tightly tied and managed in practice by the same team could perfectly be in the same microservice. Chris Richardson, who "invented" the microservice concept wrote multiple articles on patterns and anti-patterns regarding decomposition strategies for microservices, which are really worth reading (e.g on microservices.io or his book, which is masterpiece on modern architectures).


I see it often recommended that each service should have their own database to minimize coupling which makes sense.

I think there's an issue with terminology that creates a lot of confusion when it comes to SOA.  What do we mean by the word 'service'?  If we go back to the bad ol' days when SOA was primarily built with SOAP/WSDL, the word 'service' had a specific meaning: "a set of system functions that have been exposed to the Web-based protocols." That is, a 'service' explicitly defined as a collection of service operations.
Later, as REST-style services supplanted SOAP/WSDL, the term 'service' became much more nebulous. There's no specific concrete component of a REST-style solution that has that name. REST talks about resources and methods.  What does the term 'service' refer to in REST? I argue that it is ambiguous.
Here's where I think the problem comes in. It seems like a lot of people take 'service' to mean either a single endpoint or maybe a resource. They might even go as far to assume that every method (e.g. GET or POST) is a 'service'. If you take that understanding and combine it with the idea that every service needs its own database, you end up with something that's pretty absurd, from a technical perspective.
I think we need to go back to the WSDL concept of a 'service' and clarify what the analog to that is in REST-style services.  I would argue that it should be interpreted to mean a domain or even a collection of tightly coupled domains.
Now, the specifics
You mention:

products
product categories
sellers
campaigns
payments

First off, products and product categories, that's one 'service'. Unless you can explain to me why they need to be independent, that seems like a no-brainer. If someone tells you that they need to be separate services with separate databases for 'reasons', I think you can comfortably assume that person is operating as a member of a cargo-cult.
For the others, it's not so clear. You ask:

And maybe, over time, both the "payments" service and "campaigns" service need to know which product belongs to which seller.

OK. Perhaps that is true. The question is: why can't the 'payments' and 'campaigns' service retrieve the data from the 'products' and 'seller' services as needed? Is there a performance issue that reasonable caching won't solve?
There's also the whole HATEOAS approach. Despite possibly being the worst acro-initialism ever devised; I think there's a really good reason to take time to wrap one's head around it. Essentially, the idea is that your services don't need to know anything about each other. The clients of those services put it together.
As a simple example, it doesn't make sense to have 'payments' without a 'seller' or a 'customer' but the 'payments' service likely doesn't need to know the details of either.  It just needs an identifier. The client can retrieve a 'payment' record which contains an identifier for the 'seller' and an identifier for the 'customer' and retrieves whatever details it needs from those corresponding services.
The reason this is a useful approach is that trying to create services that aggregate over other services leads to a lot of intractable problems without solving much.

I really find it quite doubtful that a computer system for somehow administering payments "doesn't need to know" details about sellers or customers. Even in terms of the record keys you mention, there is a benefit from transactional consistency - unless some payments with wrong keys can go into suspense, and you have a whole system for that including manning it with staff to clear the backlog of mismatches. Where that function exists, it's because the system has to work decentralised and can't have real-time consistency, not because it "doesn't need" consistency. (1/2)

"The clients of those services put it together." - isn't this just what a database engine does? It gets data from multiple tables and puts it together for the client? Except solutions for dealing with all the common overheads, like making a reliable update to more than one table, or taking a consistent backup, are already baked into the engine technology? (2/2)

@Steve Yes a single database can do that.  When have separate databases, as in the context of the question, that doesn't work.

@Steve "I really find it quite doubtful that a computer system for somehow administering payments "doesn't need to know" details about sellers or customers." What details about the customers and sellers do you think a payment tracking system needs, exactly?

Well the fact of their existence on record for a start - that is, whether the key itself is valid, and potentially cross-referencing more details to ensure the key isn't another valid one but misquoted. Then maybe allocating the payment to specific invoices. In a minority of cases these activities also become non-trivial due to confused or corrupt information supplied, and the need to resolve these cases. And if we're talking about something like PayPal, then fraud, money-laundry, and KYC checks. It's very narrow minded these claims that certain things "don't need to be known".

@Steve All of those details can be retrieved from the services that are dedicated to managing that information.  You don't need to store data locally to be able to do these things.

But you're moving from saying you "don't need to know" any extra details, to saying a few examples off my cuff might be useful and can be fetched on demand. It's basically the analogy of saying you don't have to put everything in the same database table - you can use two tables, and join on demand. Sure! The issue here isn't that you can't store two pieces of data apart - it's that the need for a combination is presented at first as completely implausible, and then having found counter-examples of common combinations, rejoining the data siloed in different services is presented as a triviality

@Steve Frankly, it doesn't seem like you really understand the basics of the architectural style being discussed and I have no interest in explaining them to you.

I think I do understand what's being said, I just find it absurd and unconvincing - a finding which you have no interest in changing. It's fits a pattern that even comes with its own jargon - always someone talking about what you "don't need to know", as if the predominant problem all those silly monolith designers have, is not realising how much data they didn't need to co-locate!

@Steve I really don't care about what you are saying.

We seem to get this all the time here now - although I don't know whether it's actually becoming more common, or I'm just noticing it more.
A "microservice" is something akin in scale to an entire database application, not a single database table.
What makes the service "micro" is that the entire thing is capable of being looked after by a small dedicated team, and they're capable of executing their daily work (modifying their software, taking it offline for a few hours, deploying updates, etc.) with a reasonable amount of autonomy from any other team who look after different services.
This is in contrast to monoliths that grow to a scale where dozens of people at once are looking after it, like a legion of masons around the same cathedral, and it's either online or offline as a whole.
A solo developer does not generally split things that are related or which share data into "microservices", unless there is some special deployment context.
Crucially, the point of a microservice is to make development easier for multiple teams, when development is being done on a scale that requires enough staff to fill multiple teams - for the one-man-band, it only makes things harder than it would be to look after a monolith of equivalent functionality, which is why you never split things up if you don't have to.
You also don't atomise things to the point where you can't get anything useful done at all without yoking multiple microservices together. This is just a monolith in reality, with all the expensive trappings and overheads of microservices but none of the advantageous qualities.
A single microservice can nevertheless have an extremely rich store of data with complex internal relationships. The only limit is ensuring that the complexity stays within the scope of a single individual or, at most, a small team.
Managing the development of a piece of software that concerns products, sellers, and campaigns, is unlikely to be something that blows a single developer out of the water, let alone requires a team each.
Indeed you might well have teams of merchandisers, salesmen, and marketers, but you don't typically have a team of software developers attached to each just to manage the data processing needs of those business functions.

This point needs more emphasis: the number of micro-services = (n) * the number of teams you have. Where (n) is typical a number you can count on one hand. Since each team has to maintain (n) services and the real question is what is the MicroService buying you?

I appreciate the insights. But let's take something like Amazon with sellers, products and campaigns. The premise of my question is that the product's scale justifies splitting it into services and multiple teams. It's easy for me to imagine multiple of those services are interested in some core relations such as products and who sells them.

And indeed, microservices are micro from corporation-point-of-view. When an individual developer hears "microservice" they are biased to think about something much smaller and end up with too granular services.

The amount of change (number of new feature per time) justifies total developer count**. Teams and (Micro)Services are techniques that MIGHT help manage the interactions/complexities of large numbers of developers. However both large teams and micro-services have their own overheads. So unless you can identify a problem that they are solving (or prove that removing them causes a problem), the overhead they introduce may not be an overall win for the company. ** - A single developer can maintain a huge code base, if it changes very infrequently.

@DavidT, I would be even more emphatic: the number of micro-services = the number of teams you have looking after micro-services! A team consisting of something between one and a few people. That really is the core principle.

@Antti_M, yes, let's take something like Amazon and then accept that you're not responsible for organising development work at a trillion dollar platform which sells almost every type of consumer good the world economy makes! I'm prepared to accept that there is something about the scale of "products" at Amazon that could require its own development team, although I have no actual evidence that it has a "products microservice". (1/3)

In any company I've worked in, a computerised products list is not something that poses development challenges in its own right. Most of the hassle is around users maintaining a large catalog in proper order, not the software/technical aspects of designing and maintaining the data storage facility for that catalog alone - which is often a very moderate number of tables and screens. (2/3)

More broadly, the complexity in corporate ERP applications owes to how different pieces of master data connect or how to accomodate change (alternatively put, how to record history as well as the present). In other words, it's about how data ties together and evolves together, it's never about the free-standing complexity of one area which can be managed by cutting everything up into separate services. For obvious reasons then, ERPs are always integrated monoliths, not separate services. (3/3)

@Steve "In other words, it's about how data ties together and evolves together". I think this is a concise way to put what I was trying to communicate in my question. It seems that tying together and evolving together is what tends to happen, and I was wondering how to deal with this in SOA/microservices.

@Antti_M, the basic answer is, you duplicate the data, synchronising it somehow between the services lazily or in non-real-time. Obviously, this doesn't help anything if the problem is not the perceived need to apply multiple people to the task and allow them to work with some independence from one another.

I think you have the wrong idea of microservices here. Even as a solo developer there is merit to making your application in the form of MS. There is such a thing as finishing code. If I finish the campaign MS and don't have to touch it for a year, it's great that it's a seperate MS. There's a whole bunch of benefits to not having all your code in one basket unrelated to team size

@Ewan, I'm definitely not arguing against suitable forms of modularity and internal organisation - even monoliths have this. Surely when some thinker came up with the idea of "microservices", he wasn't just telling his expert fellow practitioners not to put all their code in one file (or otherwise fail to have commonsense internal divisions and structures)?

@Steve if you replace  "file" with "application" basically yes.
